# Create typings for native javascript libary (vimeo) in angular

Tags: angular, typescript-typings, angular-library, vimeo-player

At the moment I'm refactoring some of my angular libraries into an NX workspace. The workspace consists of multiple separate libraries for video players.

[image: My NX workspace]

**@types** only contains types for YouTube, but not for DailyMotion, Vimeo (not the right ones) nor SoundCloud. In the past I was able to solve this by adding a file

src/lib/interfaces/vimeo.ts

```
declare namespace Vimeo {
    export class Player {
        ...
    }
}
```

to my workspace, and referencing it like this in my component:

```
/// <reference path="../../interfaces/vimeo.ts" />

@Component({
  selector: 'vimeo-player'
})
export class VimeoPlayerComponent { }
```

This would cause the production build to succeed.

[Here's what the angular documentation has to say about this topic](https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries#library-typings).

But if I try to do the same in my new project, I'm getting the following message from NX:

[image: Do not use a tripple slash reference for, use import style instead]

So I've tried to solve it by:

- Moving my type-declarations file to `src/types/vimeo/index.d.ts`
- Modifying `tsconfig.lib.json`

  - Add to types: `"types": [ "node", "vimeo" ]`
  - Include the file: `"include": ["**/*.ts", "src/types/vimeo/index.d.ts"]`
- Reference the namespace from my component:

'

```
import 'vimeo';
import { ... } from '...';

@Component({
  selector: 'vimeo-player',
})
export class VimeoPlayerComponent {
    ...
}
```

Now in VS Code I can litterally click through to the Vimeo player from my component, So I would assume that the declaration file should be working as expected, but still when running

```
npm run nx run-many -- --target=build --projects=mintplayer-ng-player-progress,mintplayer-ng-vimeo-api,mintplayer-ng-vimeo-player --configuration production
```

I'm still getting the following errors:

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'vimeo'.
    The file is in the program because:
        Entry point of type library 'vimeo' specified in compilerOptions
   libs/mintplayer-ng-vimeo-player/src/lib/components/vimeo-player/vimeo-player.component.ts:40:29 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Vimeo'.

   40           this.player = new Vimeo.Player(this.domId, {
                                  ~~~~~
```

This used to work fine, compile without errors, like [here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-vimeo-player/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-vimeo-player/src/lib/components/vimeo-player/vimeo-player.component.ts), but now I'm getting the above errors. The new repository (NX workspace) is [pushed here](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/ng-video-player).

What is the recommended way of consuming native javascript libraries and add typings in angular as of today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to get it to work by putting the types [like here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-video-player/tree/master/libs%2Fmintplayer-ng-video-player%2Fsrc%2Ftypes) and referencing this folder from the [`tsconfig.lib.json`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-video-player/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-video-player/tsconfig.lib.json#L9). The `types` folder MUST contain a folder named after your desired typing (eg **vimeo**), and within the `index.d.ts`.

There need to be no `import` statements in your typescript code.

Sadly it appears you have to do this for each application/library that needs the javascript library types.